# RabbitMQ: Verify version of rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I verify which version of rabbitmq is running on a server?

Is there a command to verify that rabbitmq is running?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Use this command:

```bash
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

and look for line that looks like this:

```erlang
{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.6.1"},
```

Comment: I got this instead on Archlinux - [{rabbit,34362},{rabbitmqctl23794,40359}] though I installed rabbitmq 3.1.3-1 :)

Comment: And if rabbitmq services are stopped? It doesn't works.
How can I retrieve version of a "shut down" rabbitmq?

Comment: In Windows this is very similar. 
"C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin\rabbitmqctl status"
Folder name may vary with your version of Rabbit.

Answer (score 41):

You can simply execute from the command line:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status | grep rabbit
```

Comment: Maybe the format has changed - as of version `3.8.4`, a better search string is `sudo rabbitmqctl status | grep -i "version"`.

Answer (score 27):

If rabbitimq can not start I found the only way to determine version is via installer system.

Eample Debian/Ubuntu:

```
dpkg -s rabbitmq-server | grep Version
```

Comment: or `yum list rabbitmq-server` for Rhel/Centos/Fedora

Answer (score 12):

If you have no access to rabbitmqctl or rabbitmq-server is not running, on linux do :

```
ls /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/
```

I got :

```
rabbitmq_server-3.5.6
```

Answer (score 10):

As Marek said on a local server, or, on a remote server (using [amqplib](http://code.google.com/p/py-amqplib/)):

```
from amqplib import client_0_8 as amqp
import sys

conn = amqp.Connection(host=sys.argv[1], userid="guest", password="guest", virtual_host="/", insist=False)

for k, v in conn.server_properties.items():
    print k, v
```

Save as `checkVersion.py` and run with `python checkVersion.py dev.rabbitmq.com`:

```
% python checkVersion.py dev.rabbitmq.com
information Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
product RabbitMQ
copyright Copyright (C) 2007-2011 VMware, Inc.
capabilities {}
platform Erlang/OTP
version 2.6.0
```

Comment: This worked for me but wonly with Python3 and I had to create checkVersion.py under the folder client_0_8 (in windows)

Answer (score 3):

On debian systems, you can just run:

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}' --show rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 2):

To get RabbitMQ version using the [.NET/C# RabbitMQ Client Library](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html):

```cs
using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    if (connection.ServerProperties.ContainsKey("version"))
        Console.WriteLine("Version={0}",
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])connection.ServerProperties["version"]));
}
```

Output:

> Version=3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

Since I was looking to do this in C# on a Windows machine and all the current answers are for *nix, I'll post the code that I ended up using:

```cs
public string GetRabbitMqVersion()
{
    string prefix = "rabbitmq_server-";
    var dirs = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server", string.Format("{0}*",prefix));

    foreach (var dir in dirs)
    {
        //Just grab the text after 'rabbitmq_server-' and return the first item found
        var i = dir.LastIndexOf(prefix);
        return dir.Substring(i+16);
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the likely event you're using the "management" (web) plug-in, the RabbitMQ version appears in the upper-right corner of every web page, along with the version of the Erlang run-time.

Answer (score 1):

I use following command to trim output down to version,

```
rabbitmqctl status | grep "{rabbit,\"RabbitMQ\""
```

**Output:**

```
  {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.7.3"},
```

Answer (score 0):

On Centos you can use `yum list rabbitmq-server`.

Answer (score 0):

MQ serer installation steps

sudo apt update

sudo apt install curl software-properties-common apt-transport-https lsb-release

apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt install curl software-properties-common apt-transport-https lsb-release

curl -fsSL https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/erlang_solutions.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/erlang.gpg

echo "deb https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/erlang.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install erlang

erl

curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

sudo apt update

sudo apt install rabbitmq-server

systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service

systemctl is-enabled rabbitmq-server.service

sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

sudo ss -tunelp | grep 15672

sudo rabbitmq-plugins list -v

sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_mqtt rabbitmq_web_stomp rabbitmq_amqp1_0

systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service

Comment: var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var mqttUrl = 'mqtt://localhost';
var device_id = "5";
var mqttOption = {
    clientId: "52",
    port: 1883,
    username: "",
    password: "",
    // port: 8883,
    // username: "iothub.azure-devices.net/"+device_id+"/?api-version=2018-06-30",
    // password: "sas token",
    // rejectUnauthorized: false,
    // reconnecting: true,
    // reconnectPeriod: 25000,
    // connectTimeout: 50000
};
var mqttClient = "";
var pubTopic = "devices/" + device_id + "/messages/events/";
var subTopic = "devices/" + device_id + "/messages/devicebound/#";

Comment: try {
    mqttClient = mqtt.connect(mqttUrl, mqttOption);
    
    mqttClient.on('connect', function () {
        console.log("Device connected 12");
        setInterval(() => {
            var data = {
                id: device_id,
                temp: RandFunc(15, 20),
                humid: RandFunc(30, 50),
                mot: RandFuncFromArray(["ON", "OFF"]),
            };
            console.log(data);
            mqttClient.publish(pubTopic, JSON.stringify(data));
             
        }, 5000);

Comment: mqttClient.publish("devices/" + device_id + "/messages/events/", '{"id":123}', qos=1)
        mqttClient.subscribe(subTopic);
    })
    
    mqttClient.on("message", function (topic, payload) {
        console.log("new command :::::::::::::::::::: ", topic,  JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(payload)) );
    })

    mqttClient.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("Error => ", err.message);
    });

    mqttClient.on('close', function () {
        console.log("Connection closed => ");
    })

Comment: } catch (error) {
   console.log("close => ", error.message);
}

function RandFunc(min, max) {
    return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(0);
}

function RandFuncFromArray(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  }

Answer (score -1):

Login to management ui and in top right you can find the version. Also use the following command to find the version

`# sudo bash`

`# rabbitmqctl status | grep rabbit`