# RabbitMQ 3.3.1 can not login with guest/guest

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed the latest version of RabbitMQ on a VPS Debian Linux box. Tried to get login through guest/guest but returned with the message **login failed**. I did a little research and found that for security reason its prohibited to get login via guest/guest remotely.

I also have tried enabling guest uses on this version to get logged in remotely by creating a `rabbitmq.config` file manually (because the installation didn't create one) and placing the following entry only

```
[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

after restart the rabbitmq with the following command.

```
invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server stop -- to stop
invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start -- to start
```

It still doesn't logged me in with guest/guest. I also have tried installing RabbitMQ on Windows VPS and tried to get log in via guest/guest through localhost but again i get the same message **login failed**.

Also provide me a source where I could try installing the old version of RabbitMQ that does support logging remotely via guest/guest.

Comment: Please read this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install/22854222#22854222

Comment: Thanks Gabriele this worked for me following your link. I ended up creating a new test user and giving it the correct permissions

Comment: Here is the correct answer which helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29344487/1491359

Comment: I encountered a similar issue and found following actions are helpful for debugging. Try to start `rabbitmq-server` directly. If it fails, try to find useful information in the log file. On Ubuntu, log file is located in `/var/log/rabbitmq/`.

Answer (score 288):

I had the same Problem..

I installed RabbitMQ and Enabled Web Interface also but still couldn't sign in with any user i newly created, this is because you need to be administrator to access this.

Do not create any config file and mess with it..

This is what i did then,

1. Add a new/fresh user, say user `test` and password `test`:

   ```
   rabbitmqctl add_user test test
   ```
2. Give administrative access to the new user:

   ```
   rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator
   ```
3. Set permission to newly created user:

   ```
   rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
   ```

That's it, enjoy :)

Comment: This was the way to go.  easy peasy.

Comment: Once I executed those 3 command lines, I can access RabbitMQ management console from remote

Comment: It worked. Thank you. For me restart required after these 3 steps

Comment: I think that only tag `management` is required to be able to log into web interface. Tag `administrator` is extended version of `management` permission https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#permissions

Comment: Thanks, works nicely on Windows Server

Comment: This works in 2022. A service restart was not necessary for me. OP, why is this answer not accepted?

Comment: This was required for 3.7.6, but not 3.13.0 on my end. RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE also apparently doesn't work in 3.7.6 but works in 3.13.0 (and apparently is depreciated), I had to use .erlang.cookie instead. Adding this here in case someone comes across it.

Answer (score 91):

I tried on Debian the same configuration with the following steps:

1. Installed RabbitMQ.
2. Enabled the web-management plug-in (not necessary).

When I tried to login I had the same error:

[image]

So I created a `rabbitmq.config` file ([classic configuration file](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file)) inside the `/etc/rabbitmq` directory with the following content (notice the final dot):

> [{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].

Alternatively, one can create instead a `rabbitmq.conf` file ([new configuration file](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#erlang-term-config-file)) inside the same directory with the following content:

> loopback_users = none

Then I executed the `invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start` command and both the console and the Java client were able to connect using the guest/guest credentials:

[image]

So I think you have some other problem if this procedure doesn't work. For example your RabbitMQ might be unable to read the configuration file if for some reason you have changed the `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable.

Comment: This also did not work for me on Ubuntu 14. It appears to ignore /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

Comment: I found that installing rabbit using instructions for Ubuntu on the official site, the config file was missing for me as well. This answer fixed that.

Answer (score 24):

This is a new features since the version 3.3.0. You can only login using guest/guest on localhost. For logging from other machines or on ip you'll have to create users and assign the permissions. This can be done as follows:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user test test
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

Answer (score 11):

Adding the below line in the config file and restarting the server worked for me. Kindly try in your setup.

```
loopback_users.guest = false
```

I got this line from the example RabbitMQ config file from Github as linked [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/376cc34183d8760ca11f925f51cf036c91b078e3/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example#L97).

Answer (score 7):

notice: check your PORT is 15672 !  (version > 3.3 )  if 5672 not works

First of all, check the "choosen answer above":

```
rabbitmqctl add_user test test
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

and if still can't make connection work, check if your port is correct!

for me, this command works:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin -H 10.140.0.2 -P 15672 -u test -p test list vhosts
+------+----------+
| name | messages |
+------+----------+
| /    |          |
+------+----------+
```

for the completed ports , check this: 
[What ports does RabbitMQ use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792856/what-ports-does-rabbitmq-use)

to verify your rabbit mq server, check this:  [Verify version of rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593269/verify-version-of-rabbitmq)

p.s.

For me, after I created the "test" user and run `set_user_tags`, `set_permissions` , I can't connect to rabbitmq via port 5672. but I can connect via 15672.

However, port 15672 always gives me a "blank response".  and my code stop working.

so about 5 minutes later,  I switched to 5672, everything worked!

Very wired problem. I have no time to dig deeper. so I wrote it down here for someone meeting the same problems.

Comment: This really helped me, thank you. The official website meanders way too much for my taste -- I simply want command examples doing common admin activities, and your comment was much more helpful than the official website.

Answer (score 5):

for other guys which use Ansible for RabbitMQ provisioning, what I missed for `rabbitmq_user` module was `tags: administrator`

here is my working Ansible configuration to recreate "guest" user (for development environment purpose, don't do that in production environment):

`- name: Create RabbitMQ user "guest"
  become: yes
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: guest
    password: guest
    vhost: /
    configure_priv: .*
    read_priv: .*
    write_priv: .*
    tags: administrator
    force: yes # recreate existing user
    state: present`

and I also had to setup a file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` containing the following:

`[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].`

in order to be able to log using "guest"/"guest" from outside of localhost

Comment: just had this use case...created a rabbit user with ansible and I couldn't log through the web....this worked!

Answer (score 5):

#Create rabbitmq.conf file with

rabbitmq.conf

```
loopback_users = none
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.7-management

#Rabbitmq config
COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

#Install vim (edit file)
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "vim"]

#Enable plugins rabbitmq
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_mqtt rabbitmq_federation_management rabbitmq_stomp
```

Run:

```
$ docker build -t  my-rabbitmq-image .

$ docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672  my-rabbitmq-image
```

Check that the rabbitmq.conf file has been copied correctly.

```
$ docker exec -it my_container_id /bin/bash

$ vim /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

Comment: Note in this line that should run the container's bash `docker exec -it my_container_id /bin/bash`, it should be `./bin/bash`, with a `.` before the path. Otherwise, at least on Windows, it seems Docker treats it as a local path in the host system.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I tried what was suggested by Gas and ran "invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start" it didn't start. I tried to reboot the server and the webui worked with the guest user. Maybe after adding the rabbitmq.config file, something else also needed to started.

I used rabbitmq version 3.5.3.

One more thing to note: if you're using AWS instance then you need to open inbound port 15672. (The port for RabbitMQ versions prior to 3.0 is 55672.).

Answer (score 2):

Students and I stared at this problem for an hour.  Be sure you've named your files correctly.  In the `/etc/rabbitmq` directory, there are two distinct files.  There is an `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` file which you should edit to get the loopback users as described, but there is another file called `rabbitmq-env.conf` file.  Many folks were using tab completion and just adding "ig", which isn't the right file.  Double check!

Answer (score 2):

sometimes you don't need the comma ,   which is there in the configuration file by default , if nothing else is configured below  rabbit tag ,  while starting broker 
we will get a crash

like 
 {loopback_users, []} , I spend many times hours forgetting this and later removing the comma , it is applicable for all other configurations including SSL

Answer (score 2):

Try restart your rabbitmq and login again, for me work.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different use, but might be useful for anyone dealing with accessing the API for monitoring purposes:
I can confirm the answer given by @Oliboy50 works well, **however** make sure you enable it for each vhost you want the user to be able to monitor, such as:

```
      permissions:
    - vhost: "{{item.name}}"
      configure_priv: .*
      write_priv: .*
      read_priv: .*
  state: present
  tags: management
with_items: "{{user_system_users}}"
```

With this loop I was able to get past the "401 Unauthorized" error when using the API for any vhost.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the guest user is prohibited from connecting from remote hosts; it can only connect over a loopback interface (i.e. localhost). This applies to connections regardless of the protocol. Any other users will not (by default) be restricted in this way.

> It is possible to allow the guest user to connect from a remote host
>   by setting the loopback_users configuration to none

```
# DANGER ZONE!
#
# allowing remote connections for default user is highly discouraged
# as it dramatically decreases the security of the system. Delete the user
# instead and create a new one with generated secure credentials.
loopback_users = none
```

Or, in the classic config file format (rabbitmq.config):

```
%% DANGER ZONE!
%%
%% Allowing remote connections for default user is highly discouraged
%% as it dramatically decreases the security of the system. Delete the user
%% instead and create a new one with generated secure credentials.
[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

See at ["guest" user can only connect from localhost](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#loopback-users)

TIP: It is advisable to delete the guest user or at least change its password to reasonably secure generated value that won't be known to the public.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues after trying to log in with empty username/password in the web login form first:

[image]

and then getting rejected after entering guest/guest into the basic authentication window of the browser:

[image]

**Solution:**

Entered guest/guest in the web form instead of the basic auth window:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you will check the log file under info report you will get this.

```
`config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config (not found)`.
```

Change the config file permission using below command then login using guest , it will work

`sudo chmod 777 /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config`