# RabbitMQ when running with <IP Address> giving AuthenticationException

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have developed a small program to connect to rabbitMQ server.
I have used all the default settings.

**Method**

```
public Connection getConnection(String host) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(host);
        return factory.newConnection();
    }
```

When I pass String `localhost`  to this method `it return me a valid connection` but when I pass my machine's IP Address `xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx` then it gives me below error 
**com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.**

I need to pass the IP Address to be able to access it from other machine.

Can anybody provide some pointers on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a permission problem using `guest` `guest`

Please read this [Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install)

Comment: I have created the `rabbitmq.config` file and added `[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]`  this string into it . but it's not working yet

Comment: please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669780/rabbitmq-3-3-1-can-not-login-with-guest-guest

Comment: For me it worked when I have created new User [admin]  and used `factory.setUserName("admin"); factory.setPassword("xxxx");` . I have given all the previliges to to admin .