# Rabbitmq hello world connection doesn't work on localhost

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I take hello world example from tutorial:

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

got error: it shouldn't be a grant user problem cause  guest/guest should be able to connect for localhost

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send.py", line 4, in <module>
    host='localhost'))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 410, in _flush_output
    self._impl.ioloop.poll()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 528, in poll
    self._process_fd_events(fd_event_map, write_only)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 443, in _process_fd_events
    handler(fileno, events, write_only=write_only)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 364, in _handle_events
    self._handle_read()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 412, in _handle_read
    return self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 288, in _handle_disconnect
    self._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 95, in _adapter_disconnect
    super(SelectConnection, self)._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 154, in _adapter_disconnect
    self._check_state_on_disconnect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 173, in _check_state_on_disconnect
    raise exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError
pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError
```

here is the rabbitmq environment:

```
Application environment of node 'rabbit@xuches-Air' ...
[{kernel,[{error_logger,tty},
          {inet_default_connect_options,[{nodelay,true}]},
          {inet_dist_listen_max,25672},
          {inet_dist_listen_min,25672}]},
 {mnesia,[{dir,"/usr/local/bin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@xuches-Air"}]},
 {os_mon,[{start_cpu_sup,false},
          {start_disksup,false},
          {start_memsup,false},
          {start_os_sup,false}]},
 {rabbit,[{auth_backends,[rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
          {auth_mechanisms,['PLAIN','AMQPLAIN']},
          {backing_queue_module,rabbit_priority_queue},
          {channel_max,0},
          {channel_operation_timeout,15000},
          {cluster_keepalive_interval,10000},
          {cluster_nodes,{[],disc}},
          {cluster_partition_handling,ignore},
          {collect_statistics,none},
          {collect_statistics_interval,5000},
          {credit_flow_default_credit,{200,50}},
          {default_permissions,[<<".*">>,<<".*">>,<<".*">>]},
          {default_user,<<"guest">>},
          {default_user_tags,[administrator]},
          {default_vhost,<<"/">>},
          {delegate_count,16},
          {disk_free_limit,50000000},
          {enabled_plugins_file,"/usr/local/bin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"},
          {error_logger,{file,"/usr/local/bin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@xuches-Air.log"}},
          {fhc_read_buffering,false},
          {fhc_write_buffering,true},
          {frame_max,131072},
          {halt_on_upgrade_failure,true},
          {handshake_timeout,10000},
          {heartbeat,60},
          {hipe_compile,false},
          {hipe_modules,[rabbit_reader,rabbit_channel,gen_server2,
                         rabbit_exchange,rabbit_command_assembler,
                         rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,rabbit_basic,rabbit_event,
                         lists,queue,priority_queue,rabbit_router,
                         rabbit_trace,rabbit_misc,rabbit_binary_parser,
                         rabbit_exchange_type_direct,rabbit_guid,rabbit_net,
                         rabbit_amqqueue_process,rabbit_variable_queue,
                         rabbit_binary_generator,rabbit_writer,delegate,
                         gb_sets,lqueue,sets,orddict,rabbit_amqqueue,
                         rabbit_limiter,gb_trees,rabbit_queue_index,
                         rabbit_exchange_decorator,gen,dict,ordsets,
                         file_handle_cache,rabbit_msg_store,array,
                         rabbit_msg_store_ets_index,rabbit_msg_file,
                         rabbit_exchange_type_fanout,
                         rabbit_exchange_type_topic,mnesia,mnesia_lib,rpc,
                         mnesia_tm,qlc,sofs,proplists,credit_flow,pmon,
                         ssl_connection,tls_connection,ssl_record,tls_record,
                         gen_fsm,ssl]},
          {log_levels,[{connection,info}]},
          {loopback_users,[<<"guest">>]},
          {memory_monitor_interval,2500},
          {mirroring_flow_control,true},
          {mirroring_sync_batch_size,4096},
          {mnesia_table_loading_timeout,30000},
          {msg_store_credit_disc_bound,{2000,500}},
          {msg_store_file_size_limit,16777216},
          {msg_store_index_module,rabbit_msg_store_ets_index},
          {msg_store_io_batch_size,2048},
          {num_ssl_acceptors,1},
          {num_tcp_acceptors,10},
          {password_hashing_module,rabbit_password_hashing_sha256},
          {plugins_dir,"/usr/local/bin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/plugins"},
          {plugins_expand_dir,"/usr/local/bin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@xuches-Air-plugins-expand"},
          {queue_index_embed_msgs_below,4096},
          {queue_index_max_journal_entries,32768},
          {reverse_dns_lookups,false},
          {sasl_error_logger,{file,"/usr/local/bin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.2/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@xuches-Air-sasl.log"}},
          {server_properties,[]},
          {ssl_allow_poodle_attack,false},
          {ssl_apps,[asn1,crypto,public_key,ssl]},
          {ssl_cert_login_from,distinguished_name},
          {ssl_handshake_timeout,5000},
          {ssl_listeners,[]},
          {ssl_options,[]},
          {tcp_listen_options,[{backlog,128},
                               {nodelay,true},
                               {linger,{true,0}},
                               {exit_on_close,false}]},
          {tcp_listeners,[5672]},
          {trace_vhosts,[]},
          {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
          {vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio,0.5}]},
 {rabbit_common,[]},
 {ranch,[]},
 {sasl,[{errlog_type,error},{sasl_error_logger,false}]},
 {stdlib,[]},
 {xmerl,[]}]
```

Anyone has an idea what is problem?

Comment: Code works correctly on my computer. Do you have a config file for rabbitmq which might ask for authentication ? For example in /etc/rabbitmq on linux

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, it has a rabbitmq.config.example in /etc/rabbitmq, how could I use it to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you post your rabbitmq environment in the question? sudo rabbitmqctl environment

Comment: Thanks!  Just added.

Comment: It weird, I ran the hello example code perfectly. I tried this command `sudo rabbitmqctl status|grep guest` and found nothing, because there is a line `{loopback_users,[<<"guest">>]},` in your post. Do you install RabbitMQ using the default configuration?

Comment: Hi Kenshinji, I just downloaded the rabbitmq zip file and exact to the /usr/local/bin. I don't know what is the default configuration. anything wrong here?

Comment: Actually I just test the code on AWS, which works. but don't know why it doesn't work on my mac

Answer (score 0):

This is an authentication problem, please read:

[Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install/22854222#22854222)

and this:

[RabbitMQ 3.3.1 can not login with guest/guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669780/rabbitmq-3-3-1-can-not-login-with-guest-guest)

If you have enabled the management UI try to access on the management UI using:

http://your_machine_ip:15672/

using `guest` `guest`

btw I suggest to create an user to access externally. as described he:
[RabbitMQ 3.3.1 can not login with guest/guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669780/rabbitmq-3-3-1-can-not-login-with-guest-guest)

Comment: Hi Gabriele, thanks! I read those post but all about log in by guest/guest remotely, which is not my case: I use the localhost which is allowed to log in by guest/guest in rabbitmq doc.