# rabbimq cluster UI not coming up

Tags: rabbitmq

i have a two node rabbit mq cluster setup .

The cluster is up and running

```
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@rabbit-slave1' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@rabbit-master','rabbit@rabbit-slave1']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@rabbit-master','rabbit@rabbit-slave1']},
 {partitions,[]}]
...done.
```

I am trying to bring the management Ui up for both master and slave . Even , after adding the management plugin , the management UI is not coming up.

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
Plugin configuration unchanged.
```

I tried adding the content mentioned in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config from below link and restarting the server

[RabbitMQ 3.3.1 can not login with guest/guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669780/rabbitmq-3-3-1-can-not-login-with-guest-guest)

even that didnt help .. Can someone please tell me if anything else need to be done to bring the UI up and running.

Comment: is the port `15672` up ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The code i used for installing Rabbit mq was setting up the port to be 55672 .

Looks like rabbitmq version 3.3.1 uses 15672 . Changed the code and re-run the script and i am able to access UI now.