# Events capturing from browser using rabbitmq

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, rabbitmq, stomp

I have created a dummy web page using html when u press the button on page this event should be captured by rabbitmq server and its entry should be added in rabbitmq queue.  how to proceed this using stomp web plugin or socket.io where username and password is guest for rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to [create another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install) user `guest` `guest` is not safe.

if you want to enable `guest` user for external IP see: [RabbitMQ 3.3.1 can not login with guest/guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669780/rabbitmq-3-3-1-can-not-login-with-guest-guest)

To use STOMP over HTTP you have to enable the [web_stomp plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html):

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp`

In the [same page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) you can find a full example.

Check also this repository:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-stomp-examples/tree/stable