# RabbitMQ on Windows Server 2016 does not recognizes rabbitmq.conf

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I installed RabbitMQ on a Windows server (`otp_win64_22.2.exe` and `rabbitmq-server-3.8.2.exe`). I also installed the *Management Console*. If I look into the file `enabled_plugins` located in `%AppData%\RabbitMQ`, I can see the following:

```
[rabbitmq_management].
```

I can also access the Management Console via http://srv:15672/, but I cannot login, since I get the following message:

> User can only log in via localhost

Thus, I created a `rabbitmq.conf` in `%AppData%\RabbitMQ` with the following content:

```
loopback_users.guest = false
```

I still cannot login. I also tried other configuration options.

**Issue**:  The RabbitMQ service does not recognizes my `rabbitmq.conf` at all. What do I miss?

Comment: might be duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669780/rabbitmq-3-3-1-can-not-login-with-guest-guest

Comment: I don't believe that this is a duplicate, since I cannot set any configuration like the port or the log level.

Answer (score 0):

I realized two two things:

**1) Diagnostics broken**

The command `rabbitmq-diagnostics -q status` created an error (unfortunately, i did not documented which).

**2) Empty log file**

The log file was quite empty. Smth. like this didn't appear in the log:

```
node           : rabbit@example
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /var/lib/rabbitmq/hare.conf (not found)
```

**Observation)**

Somehow the installation seems to be broken

**Solution)**

I decided to uninstall and reinstall RabbitMQ. Et voilà, `rabbitmq-diagnostics` shows all informations, including the path to the config file, and the `rabbitmq.conf` is recognized, since I can login to the Management UI.