# How can I get the version of a remotely running RabbitMQ server programmatically in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a node server that connects to RabbitMQ using [rabbot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rabbot). This is working fine, I can publish messages, consume messages, etc.

Now I was hoping to be able to ask the RabbitMQ server which version it is running specifically.

I was hoping I might be able to publish a message asking for the version and get the answer via a reply queue. Or I could also make the request via HTTP, I have no preference. But strangely enough, I can't find any way of doing this. Hence my question: How can I get the version of a remotely running RabbitMQ server programmatically in Node.js?

---

Non-duplicate: [Verify version of rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593269/verify-version-of-rabbitmq)

The above is not a duplicate since it doesn't require the version be found **programmatically**, nor does it offer any Node.js solutions. Also, most solutions only apply to a local rabbitmq-server, not a remote one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information by using the [HTTP API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api):

```
$ curl -4su guest:guest localhost:15672/api/overview | jq '.rabbitmq_version'
"3.6.14+2.gd704c55"
```

Note that you will have to enable the `rabbitmq_management` plugin.

If you're feeling adventurous you can also use the [`erl`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) command to connect remotely and get the list of running applications and their details. The RabbitMQ version will be the version of the `rabbit` application. This is basically how the `rabbitmqctl` script works.