# How to verify if rabbitmq is installed on windows?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, cmd, rabbitmq

Is there a way to find out if rabbitmq is installed on the machine?

Either a command line or powershell script or something in C# because I am trying to check it in my c# code.

I searched for it and found only this one, but it did not help much for my case

[Verify version of rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593269/verify-version-of-rabbitmq)

**EDIT**

Just found this code snippet in one of the answers of the above post, but not sure it is the right way

```
public string GetRabbitMqVersion()
{
    string prefix = "rabbitmq_server-";
    var dirs = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server", string.Format("{0}*",prefix));

    foreach (var dir in dirs)
    {
        //Just grab the text after 'rabbitmq_server-' and return the first item found
        var i = dir.LastIndexOf(prefix);
        return dir.Substring(i+16);
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

Comment: Anyone using this on Windows should be defining several environment variables, so to find out if it is installed, *or I suppose, has been installed before*, the quickest way would probably be to check to see if one or more of those variables have been defined. For example `Set RABBITMQ_ >NUL && Echo RabbitMQ variables are defined.`. Alternatively you could check within the users Roaming profile directory`If Exist "%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\" Echo Found profile directory.`, or its contents, for example the main config file, `If Exist "%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.conf" Echo Found main config file.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of installed software is available. What is the name of the RabbitMQ app in this list? Once this is known, it is easy to identify.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |" ^
        "Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |" ^
        "Sort-Object -Property DisplayName"
```

Comment: That looks like a working solution! I do get the list of programs installed. But I am not that thorough in powershell, could you please tell me how can I filter the records to get only rabbitmq?

Comment: Okay, I could manage to create the working solution from your answer, please let me know if the solution is fine `(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -like '*rabbitmq server*'} | Select-Object) -eq $null`

Comment: Yes, I think you have it.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says you should have a directory with the file `rabbitmqctl.bat`

The file should be placed on `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-x.x.x\sbin\`

Then you can run any command in a cmd like this `rabbitmq-service.bat status`

https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html

Comment: What about `C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-x.x.x\sbin\ `?

Comment: This path should be the path where you've installed the rabbitmq.

Comment: omeninocloud, if the OP knew where the end user had installed it, they wouldn't be asking if there was a way of finding out if it was installed; they would already know. Even if the software was installed in the default location, depending upon the bitness of the software and/or OS, that could be in either `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`. Also the end user could probably, regardless of whether they are using the Windows installer, or Chocolatey, or manual methods, choose an alternative installation directory anywhere else.